# How do I replace all files in a folder with one file?

Tags: rename, file-copy

I have one file, let's call it `image.png`. I also have a folder of files like so:

```
picture.png
file.png
screenshot.png
art.png
painting.png
```

And so on.

What I want to do is replace each file inside the folder with `image.png`, but I want to keep the name of the original (so `picture.png` is still called `picture.png`, but when viewed contains `image.png`.

`image.png` does not have to be located inside the folder.

I've tried this so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for file in 'folder' 
do
    cp -f 'image.png'  $file
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cp` should do what you want. The problem is that you are not iterating through a folder. You are only doing one iteration with the `"folder"` being the contents of the `$file` variable. Try iterating over the file globbing, like this:

```
for file in folder/* 
do
    cp -vf 'image.png'  "$file"
done
```

I added a `-v` so you can get more verbose output to see any error, but you could leave that off once you get the correct results.